# Angular upgrade from 8 to 9.1

Tags: jquery, angular, angular9

i have updated angular application from angular 8 to angular 9.I m facing the below error after update.

```
Error TS2592: Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i @types/jquery` and then add `jquery` to the types field in your tsconfig.
```

I have used jquery in my application.
I have even installed @types/jquery still i m getting this error

how to resolve this error/

Comment: did you add jquery to types array in tsconfig as mentioned in error itself?

Comment: "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "../src/typings.d.ts"
    ],  like this i hav added

Comment: The error clearly states: `add jquery to the types field in your tsconfig`

Comment: yeah i hav resolved it thanks